# Openfoam, multiphaseInterfoam, non-constant inlet

Tags: openfoam

I run multiphaseInterfoam, and I have trouble with the inlet being non-constant (I want it to be constant.)

Here are my alpha-files\

> /*--------------------------------*- C++
>   -*----------------------------------*\
>
> FoamFile {
>       version     2.0;
>       format      ascii;
>       class       volScalarField;
>       location    "0";
>       object      alpha.air; } // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
>
> dimensions      [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
>
> internalField   uniform 0;
>
> boundaryField {
>       //- Set patchGroups for constraint patches
>       #includeEtc "caseDicts/setConstraintTypes"
>
> ```
> inlet
> {
>     type            alphaContactAngle;
>     thetaProperties
>     (
>         ( freshWater air ) 90 0 0 0
>         ( saltWater air ) 90 0 0 0
>         ( freshWater saltWater ) 90 0 0 0
>     );
>     value           uniform 0;
> }
>
> outlet
>
> {
>     type            alphaContactAngle;
>     thetaProperties
>     (
>         ( freshWater air ) 90 0 0 0
>         ( saltWater air ) 90 0 0 0
>         ( freshWater saltWater ) 90 0 0 0
>     );
>     value           uniform 0;
>
> }
>
>     atmosphere
> {
>     type            inletOutlet;
>     inletValue      uniform 1;
>     value           uniform 1;
> }
>
>
> barge
> {
>     type            alphaContactAngle;
>     thetaProperties
>     (
>         ( freshWater air ) 90 0 0 0
>         ( saltWater air ) 90 0 0 0
>         ( freshWater saltWater ) 90 0 0 0
>     );
>     value           uniform 0;
> } }
> ```

alpha.freshwater:

> /*--------------------------------*- C++
>   -*----------------------------------*\
>
> FoamFile {
>       version     2.0;
>       format      ascii;
>       class       volScalarField;
>       location    "0";
>       object      alpha.freshWater; } // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
>
> dimensions      [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
>
> internalField   uniform 0;
>
> boundaryField {
>       //- Set patchGroups for constraint patches
>       #includeEtc "caseDicts/setConstraintTypes"
>
> ```
> inlet
> {
>     type            fixedValue;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> outlet
> {
>     type            variableHeightFlowRate;
>     lowerBound      0;
>     upperBound      1;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> atmosphere
> {
>     type            inletOutlet;
>     inletValue      $internalField;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> barge
> {
>     type            zeroGradient;
> } }
> ```

alpha.saltWater

> FoamFile {
>       version     2.0;
>       format      ascii;
>       class       volScalarField;
>       location    "0";
>       object      alpha.saltWater; } // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
>
> dimensions      [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
>
> internalField   uniform 0;
>
> boundaryField {
>       //- Set patchGroups for constraint patches
>       #includeEtc "caseDicts/setConstraintTypes"
>
> ```
> inlet
> {
>     type            fixedValue;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> outlet
> {
>     type            variableHeightFlowRate;
>     lowerBound      0;
>     upperBound      1;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> atmosphere
> {
>     type            inletOutlet;
>     inletValue      $internalField;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> barge
> {
>     type            zeroGradient;
> } }
> ```
>
> //
>   ************************************************************************* //

alphas

> /*--------------------------------*- C++
>   -*----------------------------------*\
>
> FoamFile {
>       version     2.0;
>       format      ascii;
>       class       volScalarField;
>       location    "0";
>       object      alphas; } // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
>
> dimensions      [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
>
> internalField   uniform 0;
>
> boundaryField {
>       //- Set patchGroups for constraint patches
>       #includeEtc "caseDicts/setConstraintTypes"
>
> ```
> inlet
> {
>     type            fixedValue;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> outlet
> {
>     type            variableHeightFlowRate;
>     lowerBound      0;
>     upperBound      1;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> atmosphere
> {
>     type            inletOutlet;
>     inletValue      $internalField;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> barge
> {
>     type            zeroGradient;
> } }
> ```
>
> //
>   ************************************************************************* //

The above gives the following, wanted, distribtion of fluids for timestep 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cFQP.png)

However, after several time the above changes, also at the inlet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz8Ge.png)

I really don't understand the contactAngle functino used in alpha.air above. I have tried with the following alpha.air

> /*--------------------------------*- C++
>   -*----------------------------------*\
>
> FoamFile {
>       version     2.0;
>       format      ascii;
>       class       volScalarField;
>       location    "0";
>       object      alpha.air; } // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
>
> dimensions      [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
>
> internalField   uniform 0;
>
> boundaryField {
>       //- Set patchGroups for constraint patches
>       #includeEtc "caseDicts/setConstraintTypes"
>
> ```
> inlet
> {
>     type            fixedValue;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> outlet
> {
>     type            variableHeightFlowRate;
>     lowerBound      0;
>     upperBound      1;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> atmosphere
> {
>     type            inletOutlet;
>     inletValue      $internalField;
>     value           $internalField;
> }
>
> barge
> {
>     type            zeroGradient;
> } }
> ```
>
> //
>   ************************************************************************* //

With the alpha.air above I get a long error message that includes stuff that is interpreted as internet links so that I am not allowed to pulblish them here. The error message can be seen on [this link to the CDF-online forum](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-solving/198895-multiphaseinterfoam-non-constant-inlet.html#post682172), where I have also have asked this question.

Does anybvody know how to modify the above files to make the distribution of alpha's at the inlet constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last version of alpa.air I changed from "internalField uniform 0" to "internalField uniform 1", and now the inlet is constant. I think the internalFIeld value has to equal the default value set in setFieldsDict.